# Amplify Put Issues

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am having some trouble with the put method of the React-Native api. Here is my code:

```
Storage.put(this.props.noteId, JSON.stringify(newNote), {
            level: 'private',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
```

When run I get this error message:
[image]

However, when I run this code it works perfectly fine:

```
Storage.put(this.props.noteId, JSON.stringify(newNote), {
            level: 'protected',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
```

Here is the relevant part of my IAM policy for S3:
[image]

I can successfully perform a get and list on the private directory, and can do put on protected and public just fine, with the same and other data. I'm starting to suspect this is just a bug in Amplify, but maybe I'm missing something, any help would be appreciated.